# loading data from site as String(Android)

Tags: android

I know how to load site's content in Android using WebView (webview.loadUrl("http://slashdot.org/");)

And how can I put site's content in String variable(After I'd like to parse this string to XML but this is next problen)

Comment: Instead of using the WebView you could use the HTTPClient API and perform a GET request. Then you will get an InputStream which you could consume to get the String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pragmatical answer to your question:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.spartanjava.com");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
String result = "";

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
      response.getEntity().getContent()
    )
  );

String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
  result += line + "\n";
}

// Now you have the whole HTML loaded on the result variable
```

http://www.spartanjava.com/2009/get-a-web-page-programatically-from-android/

Comment: Of course, it wouldn't hurt to test the getStatusLine of the response for a potential error. Also, I found that the connection may be interrupted without any exception raised (where an InterruptedIOException could have been expected), so checking for the length or checksum is good too