# how to download website content (text) to String in Android Studio

Tags: android, string, tostring

I'm new in Android developing, and have start first real app which need to download content from website and convert it to a String (can be source code or something, i will cut what I need). I've searched stackoverflow and whole internet for 3 days but my low skills don't give me working app, always was some errors, missing class etc., 
this links dont hepl me: 
[Get text from web page to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418021/get-text-from-web-page-to-string)
[Android: get HTML from web page as String with HttpClient not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994777/android-get-html-from-web-page-as-string-with-httpclient-not-working)
[loading data from site as String(Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118127/loading-data-from-site-as-stringandroid)
[Downloading a website to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590899/downloading-a-website-to-a-string)
[How do you Programmatically Download a Webpage in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238547/how-do-you-programmatically-download-a-webpage-in-java)

---EDIT

This is source code i'm working now, based on http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/07/17/how-to-read-webpage-contents-as-a-string-in-android/

```
    package tm.tresura;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class HttpUtils {

  public static String getContents(String url) {
        String contents ="";

  try {
        URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection();

        InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
        contents = convertStreamToString(in);
   } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.v("MALFORMED URL EXCEPTION");
   } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(e.getMessage(), e);
   }

  return contents;
}

private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new    
                              InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         String line = null;
         try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "n");
                }
           } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           } finally {
                try {
                        is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

and errors:

```
Error:(76, 16) error: no suitable method found for v(String)
method Log.v(String,String,Throwable) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method Log.v(String,String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Error:(78, 16) error: no suitable method found for e(String,IOException)
method Log.e(String,String,Throwable) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method Log.e(String,String) is not applicable
(actual argument IOException cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion)

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: and what are those errors? and your missing class? and your code? we can't help you if you don't show anything. Take a look how to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Log.v() accepts 2 or 3 paramenters, check the method documentation first before posting question

Answer (score 1):

```
Log.v("MALFORMED URL EXCEPTION");
```

afaik `v()` has different signature, this method takes two params - tag and some body, try to add additional `String` param

```
Log.v("TAG","MALFORMED URL EXCEPTION");
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for help, maybe it was obvious for you, but not for me, I have big lack of knowledge. Now compiler works fine, but app "unexpectedly exit". I'm, working at this.